# Error: "Reply was already sent." - Fastify - No logs

Tags: node.js, fastify

I was trying to create a simple, dirty auth flow in Fastify.

Values are checked back via Prisma with a Postgres DB, checked back via bcrypt and then converted into a JWT

This is the code:

```html
const login: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.post("/", async function (request: any, reply) {
    console.log("Request");
    if (request.body.username && request.body.password) {
      await prisma.user
        .findFirst({
          where: { name: request.body.username },
        })
        .then(async (user) => {
          console.log("prisma");
          if (!user?.id) {
            console.log("User not found");
            return reply.code(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
          } else {
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(request.body.password, user!.hash)) {
              console.log("Password correct");
              await jwt.sign(
                { user: user },
                process.env.SECRET || "",
                { expiresIn: "365d" },
                (err: any, token: any) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    return reply.code(500).send({ message: "Error" });
                  } else {
                    console.log("JWT");
                    return reply.code(200).send({ jwt: token });
                  }
                }
              );
            } else {
              console.log("Password incorrect");
              return reply.code(500).send({ message: "Password incorrect" });
            }
          }
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Missing username or password");
      return reply.code(400).send({ message: "Missing user or password" });
    }
  });
}
```

I tried logging any steps, but there are no duplicate logs thrown.

This is the error:

```html
[App] Request
[App] prisma
[App] Password correct
[App] JWT
[23:29:19.419] INFO (23324): incoming request
[App]     reqId: "req-1"
[App]     req: {
[App]       "method": "POST",
[App]       "url": "/users/login",
[App]       "hostname": "127.0.0.1:3000",
[App]       "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
[App]       "remotePort": 1042
[App]     }
[App] [23:29:19.576] WARN (23324): Reply already sent
[App]     reqId: "req-1"
[App]     err: {
[App]       "type": "FastifyError",
[App]       "message": "Reply was already sent.",
[App]       "stack":
[App]           FastifyError: Reply was already sent.
[App]               at _Reply.Reply.send (C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\node_modules\fastify\lib\reply.js:118:26)
[App]               at C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\dist\routes\users\login\index.js:29:56       
[App]               at C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\node_modules\lodash.once\index.js:71:21      
[App]               at SignStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:201:9)
[App]               at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
[App]               at SignStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
[App]               at SignStream.sign (C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:64:10)
[App]               at SignStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\micha\WebstormProjects\LIBMan\backend\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:46:12)
[App]               at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
```

I apologize in advance if I am missing something obvious
The request is being returned empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found, the issue is the mix of async / await + `than` and callbacks.

It results in a code hard to read and with many edge cases because you don't know when and which code will be executed first (the callback or the statements after the await).

Note that there is the same pattern on the `prisma` query, not only on JWT code.

Let me show you the code in a full async / await style:

```js
async function login(fastify, opts) {
  fastify.post("/", async function (request, reply) {
    console.log("Request");

    // first thing first: we are avoiding to naste the code in if/else statements
    if (!request.body.username || !request.body.password) {
      console.log("Missing username or password");
      return reply.code(400).send({ message: "Missing user or password" });
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
      where: { name: request.body.username },
    })
    console.log("prisma");


    if (!user?.id) {
      console.log("User not found");
      return reply.code(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(request.body.password, user.hash)) {
      console.log("Password incorrect");
      return reply.code(500).send({ message: "Password incorrect" });
    }

    console.log("Password correct");
    const token = await jwt.sign(
      { user: user },
      process.env.SECRET || "",
      { expiresIn: "365d" },
    )

    console.log("JWT");
    // using async handlers, you can return a json instead of calling reply.send
    return { jwt: token }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake after trying a lot:

Fastify did not like how the JWT Token Sign-Process was async, it seemed to return twice.

It was as simple as changing the JWT Process to not use a callback, but rather just return as a let.

Please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473685/19832591) answer. It explains it way better and more detailed

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code was looking a bit messy so i've been so free to clear everything up a bit and hope that might work. Please tell me if the issue still persists

```
const login: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
fastify.post("/", async function (request: any, reply) {
    console.log("Request");

    if (!request.body.username || !request.body.password) {
        return reply.code(400).send({ message: "Missing user or password" });
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { name: request.body.username }})
  
    console.log("prisma");

    if(!user?.id) {
      console.log("User not found");
      return reply.code(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(request.body.password, user!.hash)) {
      console.log("Password incorrect");
      return reply.code(500).send({ message: "Password incorrect" });
    }

    console.log("Password correct");

    await jwt.sign({ user: user }, process.env.SECRET || "", { expiresIn: "365d" }, (err: any, token: any) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log("Error");
            return reply.code(500).send({ message: "Error" });
        }

        console.log("JWT");
        return reply.code(200).send({ jwt: token });
    }
});
```

}

Comment: The issue sadly still persist...

Comment: Do you have middleware that already sends a reply without returning?

Comment: @Gabe i only use [sensible](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-sensible) and nothing else.

Comment: OK! I found the problem, it doesnt like the async nature of the jwt sign process!